# Scroll overlap by header ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, components, scrollbar

I am trying to do a header Navigation in React JS.

It actually works great but the top part of my scroll (including the top-arrow) is hiddden by the header nav. My header is not a Commponent but is inside my component Home and the bar is responsive.

What should I do? Shoud I try another NavBar?

Image of the hidden scroll bar:

[image: image of the hidden scroll bar]

Comment: What does your css look like?

Comment: i just figured out thet the problem come from "position:fixed" in the css of my header. But i can't find a way to keep my header responsive, fixed and keep my entire scroll bar..

Comment: Try setting a margin top on your main content which corresponds to the height of your header.